# Difference between [weak self] and weak var weakSelf = self?

Tags: swift3, closures, cyclic-reference

I was going through closure in swift3. I read that in closure to avoid cyclic reference we declare list of captures, like [weak self].

In objective-C we used to declare weak reference to self and use that weak reference in blocks as below:

```
weak SomeClass *obj = self
```

I want to know is there any difference between both the approaches, or its just a new way of declaration in swift.

Can I declare weak reference as below in swift3:

```
weak var weakSelf = self
```

and use weakSelf in my closure?

Comment: `[weak self]` declares it in *closure scope*, `weak var weakSelf` declares it in *parent scope*. That's prime difference.

Comment: Is there any difference in memory management, with both these approaches?